# Limit related entities in Doctrine

Tags: json, symfony, doctrine-orm, knppaginator

I have the following database structure:
table of categories related to table of products with one-to-many relation

I have to produce the following JSON:

```
[
   {
      "name":"Category 1",
      "products":[
         {
            "name":"Product 1"
         },
         {
            "name":"Product 2"
         },
         ...
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"Category 2",
      "products":[
         {
            "name":"Product 3"
         },
         ...
      ]
   }
]
```

I would just serialize it, but the number of products in each category should be limited to 10 using KNP Paginator. What is the correct way to do it?

Select all categories, then select products using WHERE IN and LIMIT clauses, and then some service should attach products to categories?
I see this example: http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/yl5h/how-to-use-service-model-and-facotry-to-create-paginated-json-result-in-symfony
But looping over all categories or over all products doesn't look good for me...

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to use KNP Paginator?  Seems like this would potentially help on the PHP side for certain queries, but that what you're after is a bit more specific than a general pagination issue.  Looping through all categories and querying for products in each is a little inefficient, but depending on the nature of your data might be perfectly OK.  Failing that, I think I'd come up with a Doctrine query for categories containing a subquery returning only 10 of each product.